# How to specify multiple parameters to onClick() in an anchor tag while calling from Ajax?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function,

```
function generateEmail(caseNumber, customerCareEmailAddress) {
     var emailAddress = customerCareEmailAddress;
         window.location = "mailto:" + emailAddress + 
                           "?subject=Customer Care Case Reference %23: " +
                           caseNumber;
}
```

And this is how I call it,

```
 columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                orderable: false,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="#" id="' + 
                           row.customer_care_case_id + 
                           '" class="email icon" onClick="generateEmail(' +
                            row.case_reference_number + ',' +
                            row.customer_care_email +')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"
                                      style="color:black" ></span></a>';
                }
            }
```

But, I keep getting the following error,

`Uncaught ReferenceError: sranade@abc.com is not defined
 at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` where `sranade@abc.com` is 2nd parameter.

Am I doing anything syntactically wrong?

Comment: Try this (it is \ followed by two single quotes)
"generateEmail(\'' + row.case_reference_number + '\'

Comment: Using a template literal would really help with making the creation of your hyperlink readable.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your values in quotes, it's treating your string as a variable.

```
'<a ... onClick="generateEmail(' + row.case_reference_number + ',\'' + row.customer_care_email + '\')" .../>'
```

Or, using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`<a ... onClick="generateEmail(${row.case_reference_number}, ${row.customer_care_email})" .../>`
```